# nginx location not responding to pathnames

Tags: nginx

I've set up my site file but for whatever reason the alias isn't working. The site is an internal site and all media files are kept on a NAS off of the server. I'm trying to access them using /video/ and /pictures/ instead of the full path. However whatever I try they won't load. Can anyone help?

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    #root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    root /var/www/Misc/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name Misc;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /video/ {
            alias /media/Misc/Misc/All\ Videos/;
    }
    location /pictures/ {
            alias /media/Misc/iVideo/Library\ Caches/Misc/All\ Videos/;
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #       root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
#
    #       # With php5-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}
}
```

**UPDATE ERROR LOG EXAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
2015/03/30 20:36:35 [crit] 2919#0: *1123 open() "/media/Misc/Misc/All\ Videos/video/104567382878862660r.m4v" failed (22: Invalid argument), client: 10.0.0.80, server: misc, request: "GET /video/104567382878862660r.m4v HTTP/1.1", host: "misc", referrer: "http://misc/Videolist.php"
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The file path isn't recognised and the media isn't loaded

Comment: I get a 'Failed to load Resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) I should add I've just moved this across from using Apache and it was working fine on that.

Comment: You need to check your error logs, then.

Comment: So the config file is ok then?

Comment: How should we know? You haven't checked your error logs!

Comment: Have added an example of the error to the main post

Comment: It's changing the path. so for the video location. It is adding 'video' between the path and the filename and similar for the picture location. Any idea why?

Comment: Try `alias "/media/Misc/Misc/All Videos/";`